# Правильная настройка Denwer

Tags: denwer, windows-server

Здравствуйте. Очень сильно нужна помощь.

Есть задача установить Denwer Windows Server 2008 r2.
Однако процесс осложняется тем, что я узнал о самом Денвере в тот же день, когда мне поставили эту задачу.

Основной вопрос таков - есть ли некие подводные камни и прочие подвохи, которые могут ожидать меня в процессе установки?

И если можно, то дайте ссылку на какую нибудь статью по установке (язык статьи не сильно принципиален). Сам ничего не нашел.

Comment: Документация на [официальном сайте][1] не устраивает? Хотя, я не удивлюсь, если скажете, что да. Т.к. проект "дохлый" и пользоваться им - в принципе не рекомендую.

   [1]:http://www.denwer.ru/

Comment: В документации на оф сайте не нашел ничего об настройке на серверной ос. Только на Windows XP/7... 

Насчет "дохлости" не знаю, нету достаточного опыта чтобы судить.
Но принципиально нужно настраивать именно Денвер, преподы к нему привыкли.

Comment: @Xroft, бежал бы я от таких преподов )) В принципе, разницы нет на какой ОС ставить.

Comment: `Denwer` ставится за пару кликов. Ставите, запускаете и смотрте. Если работает как надо - не трогаем, если нет - либо сносим, либо лезем в документацию. Хотя чего там не должно работать не так, как положено `Denwer`-у?

Comment: не убегу я от них, еще несколько лет как минимум.
еще одно уточнение, если я прилеплю к денверу расширение ActivePython 2.5, то он будет поддерживать "самую-самую последнюю" версию Питона, или это придется настраивать отдельно?

Comment: @Xroft Denwer предназначен только для разработки.

Comment: А почему именно денвер? Расскажите про критерий. Чем например openserver не устраивает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ставил его на Windows Server 2012, оочень быстро все поставил и установил. НО он ооочень медленный, если сервак слабый - порой 500 ошибку кидает.
Сам когда-то искал доп.инфу по нему, но кроме официальной документации ничего не нашел.
P.S На XP кстати денвер бегает резво

Почему бы не собрать стандартный сервер (WAMP)?

Comment: Нужно ставить именно Денвер, потому как все к нему привыкли и "менять" на что-то другое отказываются. Такие дела.